# Unable to hide error msg in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

If there is no data i want to show some message. I have written the logic for that and it works. But if there is some data then also its showing the same message. No idea why its not working properly. Help will be much appreciated.

Logic in my typescript component

```
  validation: boolean; 

  constructor( ) {
    this.validation = false;
  }
searchEmployee(name: string): void {
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    const empName = name;
    let obj = { empNamewers: empName }
    let body = JSON.stringify(obj);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
     this.httpClient.post<Employee[]>('sercvicesUrl', body, config).subscribe( employees => {
        this.employees = employees;
         console.log(employees);
      if(this.employees.length === 0){
       this.validation=true;
        }
     else{
       this.validation=false;        
    }
    });

    }
```

this is HTML file

```
     <button (click)="searchEmployee(searchBox.value);">Search</button>
     <div *ngIf="validation">
    <h4>Sorry, No results</h4>
    </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be <div *ngIf="validation"> ?

Comment: Then, what it should be?

Comment: are you missing space?

Comment: It works fine if there is no data, but even if data is there it shows this msg.

Comment: While pasting here i missed, else in live code i have space.

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is that this code isn't called. Could you provide the whole code?

Comment: Is the insideSearchMethod() called anywhere in your code? Please provide more code for better understanding

Comment: Pls look at the code now @yer

Comment: Pls look at the code once @Vikas

Comment: Crete an example on stackblitz.com

Comment: Were you able to see data when you did console.log(employees)

Comment: yes, i can see.

Comment: Can you post that response here?

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code.
First, you should not assign class variables inside your constructor. That is not what constructors are for. If you assign it like this:

```
validation = false;

constructor() {}
```

Then, it will be assigned before angular lifecyles.

Secondly, in your check:

```
if(this.employees.length === 0 || this.employees.length === null){
```

This is incorrect. Length cannot be null;
It should be:

```
if (!this.employees || this.employees.length === 0) {

}
```

Here is a working example of what you are trying to achieve:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypaaea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have updated the code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using below code :

```
if(this.employees.length > 0){
    //Write you logic here
         this.validation=false;
 }
    else{
          this.validation=true;        
}
```

Always make sure that you return empty array ('[]') as API Response even you have do not have any matching data.

Comment: Thanks for ur time, but its not working this way as well.