# Hide error message if the array has elements in angular4

Tags: angular, validation, angular4-forms

I want to show a message if no data is found. I have written the logic for that and it works. However, it also displays the message when there *is* some data. I have no idea why it's not working properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Logic in my typescript component

```
validation: boolean; 
employees = [];
constructor( ) {
    this.validation = false;
}
searchEmployee(name: string): void {
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    const empName = name;
    let obj = { empNamewers: empName }
    let body = JSON.stringify(obj);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    this.httpClient.post<Employee[]>('sercvicesUrl', body, config).subscribe( employees => {
        this.employees = employees;
        console.log(employees);
        if(this.employees.length === 0){
            this.validation=true;
        }
        else{
            this.validation=false;        
        }
    });
}
```

This is HTML file :

```
 <button (click)="searchEmployee(searchBox.value);">Search</button>
 <div *ngIf="validation">
<h4>Sorry, No results</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried this `*ngIf="validation==true"`. Is it worked???

Comment: Yes, its not working.

Comment: Try `*ngIf="employees.length === 0"`.

Comment: It works for the first time when page is loaded, after that its not working on click.

Comment: You already asked the same question yesterday [Unable to hide error msg in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373058/unable-to-hide-error-msg-in-angular-4)

Comment: Yes, not getting proper answer.

Comment: what do your `employees` logs ? is there another element inside it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not subscribe to you http observable everytime you do a search, you are creating a memory leak this way, see: http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

Try:

```
employees = Observable<any[]>;
constructor( ) {
}

searchEmployee(name: string): void {
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    const empName = name;
    let obj = { empNamewers: empName }
    let body = JSON.stringify(obj);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    this.employees = this.httpClient.post<Employee[]>('sercvicesUrl', body, config)
}
```

and in you HTML:

```
<button (click)="searchEmployee(searchBox.value);">Search</button>
 <div *ngIf="!(employees | async)?.length">
<h4>Sorry, No results</h4>
</div>
```

And to display them:

```
<div *ngFor="let e of employees | async">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a method to do that as given below in your component

```
canShowErrors() {
    return (this.employees == null || this.employees.length === 0);
}
```

From the HTML you should call the

```
<button (click)="searchEmployee(searchBox.value);">Search</button>
 <div *ngIf="canShowErrors()">
<h4>Sorry, No results</h4>
</div>
```